# Varnish Inconsistently Evicting Pages from Cache

Tags: cache, varnish, configuration

In our varnish config we have a vcl_fetch function defined as follows:

```
if (beresp.ttl > 0s) {
   /* Remove Expires from backend, it's not long enough */
   unset beresp.http.expires;

   /* Set the clients TTL on this object */
   set beresp.http.cache-control = "max-age=900";

   /* Set how long Varnish will keep it */
   set beresp.ttl = 1h;

   /* marker for vcl_deliver to reset Age: */
   set beresp.http.magicmarker = "1";
 }
```

Then in vcl_deliver:

```
if (resp.http.magicmarker) {
   /* Remove the magic marker */
   unset resp.http.magicmarker;

   /* By definition we have a fresh object */
   set resp.http.age = "0";
}
```

The issue is that if I setup a script (either a shell script or a php script) to hit the same URL, I first see a MISS, followed by a HIT (all good so far).

What I am expecting to sit is repeated HITS until the 1 hour mark has passed, one MISS at the 1 hour mark, followed by an hour of HITs again. In other words because I'm hitting the same URL repeatedly it should cycle between HIT and MISS every 1 HOUR.

Instead what I see is something like this:

```
 6/20/2013 6:30:05 - STRING HIT NOT FOUND
 6/20/2013 10:32:11 - STRING HIT NOT FOUND
 6/21/2013 12:33:06 - STRING HIT NOT FOUND
 6/21/2013 2:34:06 - STRING HIT NOT FOUND
```

It's now 5:57AM (almost 4 hours since the HIT not found).

The cache misses above do all appear around the half hour mark but they're 4 hours, 2 hours and 2 hours apart and the TTL is set to 1 hour.

So I don't understand why the object is being kept longer than 1 hour and why its evicted at seemingly random intervals. How can I better determine whats going on?

By the way I am using varnish 3 if that helps.

Comment: Are those the only changes you've made to your VCL?  Why do you need to manipulate the `Age` header?  Can you provide the output from `varnishlog` for these requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the varnish server in question was caching a Drupal 7 site. In the Drupal 7 site we had the Drupal Varnish module configured and enabled.

As best as I can tell that was periodically clearing the cache. I was able to determine that using the following command and seeing BANs that I hadn't issued:

```
varnishadm -T localhost:6082 -S /etc/varnish/secret ban.list 
Present bans: 1371834738.031740 193 req.http.host ~ www.ourdomain.com && req.url ~ /
```